Stripe connect webhook for event account.updated is never triggered
I created a connect webhook to listen to the account.updated event as soon as connect account has any update but the event is not getting triggered.
But when I try to test it via CLI using the command
stripe listen -e 'account.updated' --forward-to http://localhost:7175/v2/commerce-webhooks/stripe/account/updated
I got the event in my local test environment.
Even for the event checkout.session.completed I get the webhook calls.
Flow is like, My Application requests users to link their account, once they have linked their account and all details are filled in, Stripe redirects the call to the return URL. Apart from this redirect call, I expect a webhook configured for the event account.updated but that is not getting triggered.
Just be sure that the Type is not missed, I created two webhooks one for Connect and another for Account.


You need to do
stripe listen -e 'account.updated' --forward-connect-to http://localhost:7175/v2/commerce-webhooks/stripe/account/updated

because it's a event that happens on a connected account and only is sent to Connect endpoints.
https://docs.stripe.com/cli/listen#listen-forward-connect-to
https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks

If you see the screenshot added in question, I already had a webhook with Type Connect and Account but it was not working. I removed the entry of Type Account and the trigger started working. Now I can receive the event.
